# SSIS XML Source token element truncation error

Tags: sql-server, xml, ssis, xsd

I have the following XML element pasted from an XML that I need to process in SSIS:

```
<Contact>
  <Mail>testmail@testtesttestte.com                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    </Mail>
</Contact>
```

The underling XSD schema for this XML for Mail element is:

```
            <xs:element name="Mail">
            <xs:annotation>
                <xs:documentation>e-mail address</xs:documentation>
            </xs:annotation>
            <xs:simpleType>
                <xs:restriction base="xs:token">
                    <xs:maxLength value="250"/>
                    <xs:minLength value="1"/>
                </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
        </xs:element>
```

When the SSIS package tries to process this XML it gives an error that the max size for this element was exceeded. This is due to the fact that there are 255 characters(with whitespaces) for the Mail element.
According tho this: http://www.schemacentral.com/sc/xsd/t-xsd_token.html *"each group of consecutive spaces is collapsed into one space character, and all leading and trailing spaces are removed"*

How can I make SSIS be aware of this and not give an error and be able to process the XML?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to make SSIS do what you want, but I can offer a workaround, if you want to try it: using an Execute SQL task, pass your XML into the task as a varchar variable, convert it to XML in the SQL, then manually replace your "Mail" element text, removing spaces, and pass it back out into the package variable.  Here is some sample T-SQL that you can paste into management studio to see how it could work.

```
DECLARE @mail VARCHAR(255), @xml XML = 
'<Contact>
  <Mail>testmail@testtesttestte.com                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    </Mail>
</Contact>';

SELECT  @mail = RTRIM(a.n.value('Mail[1]','varchar(max)'))
FROM    @xml.nodes('/Contact') AS a(n);

SET @xml.modify('replace value of (/Contact/Mail/text())[1] with sql:variable("@mail")')

SELECT @xml;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The reason I wanted to use SSIS was not to alter or process the XML, since the XML's that I need to process are 10GB+. I was expecting SSIS to completely read and be able to parse the XML as it is described in the XSD, but apparently it doesn't deal with the token type element.